# Smoothing graph using button

Tags: vb.net

I already have a histogram of an image using Microsoft Chart. here is the picture of histogram result :

[image: histogram]

The button i create is "histY" is the one creating the histogram on the chart. So, the button "HistNormY" is supposed to do a smoothing to this chart. I've been searching for idea to get each point value to do the smoothing. any idea how i could be able to do that? Thanks. I am using Visual Basic 2010 by the way, and i'm a newbie to ms chart in it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "smoothing"? Do you want to draw a line which roughly follows the histogram?

Comment: The 'smoothing' i mean is to distribute value so that the histogram roughly seem to have any spike peak.
The formula is :   h(x)= (h(x-1)+h(x)+h(x+1))/3